# Delphi only allow horizontal Drag-and-Drop on TControlBar

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, panel, delphi-xe4

I have a `TControlBar` aligned to the bottom of my main form (same width). The height of this Control Bar is fixed.

This Control Bar contains a number of `TPanels`, aligned horizontally (With matching heights). These panels contain various other components. I want to be able to move and rearrange these panels horizontally side-to-side but disallow vertical movement (fix Top of Panels).

How can I achieve this. I have tried setting the `Anchors->akTop` property for each Panel to `true`. But the panels sometimes move vertically as I try and drag them side to side.

I am using RAD studio XE4

Answer (score 1):

Set [`RowSize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TControlBar.RowSize) to the `Height` of the ControlBar:

> Specifies the height of the control bar's rows.

And set [`RowSnap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TControlBar.RowSnap) to `False`:

> Specifies whether controls are snapped to the control bar's rows when docked.
>
> Use RowSnap to specify whether controls are snapped to the control bar's rows when docked. Controls that are snapped have their Top and Height properties set automatically to correspond to the control bar's rows.

Comment: Thanks. I have set these properties but it still allows me to drag the band (`TPanel`) to a row that is not visible in the ControlBar. This causes the Panel to disappears, as the `height` on the ControlBar is fixed and `AutoSize` is `false`. Basically I want to limit the number of rows for the ControlBar to 1 so that panels can only be re-arranged horizontally.